# JKS Keystore entry does not contain a certificate, alias: * - Expo Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo, google-developers-console

I lost my original keystore and contacted google support to use a new one. I generated an upload certificate (pem) file to send to them.

Now, when I use expo build:android and choose to upload my own file, I get the error:

```
JKS Keystore entry does not contain a certificate, alias: mykey. Run this to find the available aliases: keytool -list -v -keystore [your-keystore-path].
```

And when I use this commend to list my aliases, mykey is available there:

```
Alias name: mykey
Creation date: Oct 12, 2021
Entry type: trustedCertEntry
```

I have tried generating a new key from the pem file.
I have tried uploading the jks file directly into the expo servers.
I have tried creating a new alias.

But all of those are not working. Anything I'm missing or approaching wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up contacting Google Support again and uploaded a new key, but this time I knew what I was doing and was able to upload it correctly.

If this happens with anyone else, make sure you understand how those keys work and how they're stored and what the difference is between the "jks" keystore and the "pem" certificate before you generate and upload a new key.

Comment: I am having exactly the same problem. What steps did you take to solve this problem? Once you had the new .pem file and .der file how did you generate the new keystore ? Was it accepted on expo.dev?